# Error encountered "Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected...."

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

We were deploying a lot of functions every day and occasionally getting this issue saying,

> "Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a
> minor monthly cost if not resolved. You can try to erase these images
> by redeploying or manually deleting them."

I'm using the Firebase-CLI command: `firebase deploy --force --only="$functions"` to deploy using shell scripts in our GitHub actions pipeline. We can still deploy after experiencing this issue, but I'd like to prevent it from appearing. As I search here, a possible reason is that the artifact registry API is not enabled, but in our case, it is already enabled. Also, I read that it could be related to payments, but our billing or payment process works fine.

The question is, how can I prevent this error from appearing? Manually deleting images in Google Cloud is extremely time consuming if you have a large number of functions to manage.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase CLI creates a `.zip` archive of the function code, which is then uploaded to a Cloud Storage bucket and that storage is billed to your account.

You can get rid of the images by using [script](https://gist.github.com/kichiemon/4ba5bf921bc9e4d208db8723da69f0ed) which mentioned in [document](https://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/firebase-gcp-saving-money). As described in the document this script will check the images in a bucket and deletes containers.

Also sharing some possible solutions discussed in [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4757) & [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3404)